# bluemix 500 error easy query

Tags: php, mysql, ibm-cloud

I am trying to do an easy query to get information from my database. When I start my browser I get an error code 500. I dont understand why. I am using bluemix devOps. this is my code :

```
<?php include 'db.php';?>

<?php

//Query to get information from the database
$strsql = "SELECT name, technology, problem FROM idea WHERE status='saved'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($strsql)) {

} else {

        echo "<b>Can't query the database;
    }

?>


      <?php
                    echo "<tr>\n";
                    while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
                            echo '<th>' .  $property->name . "</th>\n"; //the headings


                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n";

                    mysqli_data_seek ( $result, 0 );
                    if($result->num_rows == 0){ //nothing in the table
                                echo '<td>Empty!</td>';
                    }

                    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row ( $result ) ) {
                        echo "<tr>\n";
                        for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields ( $result ); $i ++) {
                            echo '<td>' . "$row[$i]" . '</td>';
                        }
                        echo "</tr>\n";
                    }

                    $result->close();
                    mysqli_close();
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in you code

```
echo "<b>Can't query the database;
```

missing doblue quote for closing

Comment: Thx that was the problem!